# Adding ApiAuthorization to .NET 8 Blazor App Causes Errors Migrating from .Net 6 WebAssembly App

Tags: c#, blazor, asp.net-core-8

I am migrating a .Net6 Web Assembly App over to .Net8 because I would like to use some of the server side rendering features.

I started with the new template and selected render mode auto as the default. That is not my main issue, but is for background.

My client pages/components use both 'public' api's (for when not logged in) and 'private' apis for when they are. (With additional functionality).

On my original .NET 6 App I am creating two seperate Http Clients in the CLient Program.cs as follows:

```
    builder.Services.AddHttpClient("RGPrivate", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress));


    builder.Services.AddHttpClient("RGPublic", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress));

    // Supply HttpClient instances that include access tokens when making requests to the server project
    builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("RGPrivate"));
```

I have replicated this in my .Net 8 Version and also added it to the Program.cs in the main 'server' app. This because my pages that I intend to run both server and client side rendering neeed some of the services that use the API... that said I did see that MS recommend (obiously) not using HttpClient on the server to call apis on the server, most of the time (if not all) this will be on the client.

The services that use the http clients inject them like this:

```
        public UserService(IHttpClientFactory HttpFactory,
        AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider
        )
    {
        _httpPrivate = HttpFactory.CreateClient("RGPrivate")  //<--This is Line 23.
          
            ;
        _httpPublic = HttpFactory.CreateClient("RGPublic");
        _authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;

    }
```

So far so good. I added:

```
   builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();
```

to the Client Program.cs (not the 'server at this stage) and though it builds I am getting an error:
[image: Error Screen]

So I realised that I had omitted to add the  `builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();` to the 'Server' app Program.cs.

I did this and then the error changes to this:
[image: 2nd Error]

Now, the PersistingRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider is added in the 'Server' Program.cs as follows:

```
 builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, PersistingRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider>();
```

Which is part of the templated code and links with the Clientside equivalent called PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider

I feel I have gone down a bit of a rabbit hole with this, but feel I am hopefully on the right sort of track. There is a comment in the 'PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider' that says:

```
    // This is a client-side AuthenticationStateProvider that determines the user's authentication state by
// looking for data persisted in the page when it was rendered on the server. This authentication state will
// be fixed for the lifetime of the WebAssembly application. So, if the user needs to log in or out, a full
// page reload is required.
//
// This only provides a user name and email for display purposes. It does not actually include any tokens
// that authenticate to the server when making subsequent requests. That works separately using a
// cookie that will be included on HttpClient requests to the server.
```

It is that Cookie working seperately that I am trying get going but I am obviously missing something. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you need to use a two step authentication.  Step 1 is to get the token/cookie.  Step 2 is to use the token to make actual request.  You are running a service.  Are you starting with "Run As"?  What account is being used. The default account for a Service is a System Account with no environment.  You may need to create a Service Account and then start the service with the Service Account instead of the default System Account.  What status code do you get when requesting the Token?  Is it 200 OK or a 400/500 Error?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean. My 'services' are just service libraries originally for the client only in the Net6 version. When you say two step, are you referring to two factor.. ? if so that has nothing to do with it. The errors are coming back from the server/ app as run time dependancy or injection errors...

Comment: You need to get a token.  Where in code are you getting token and is this successful?

Comment: It isn't succesfully running as far as being able to issue a token. In the .Net6 implementation that is handed by the builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization(); which is producing the error. I think there is some kind of conflict with the PersistingRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider or something else that I don't quite get about Blazor Server.

Comment: You must get the token working before you try anything else.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: You need to see the breaking changes going from Net 6 to Net 7 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/7.0) and then the breaking changes from Net 7 to Net 8 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/8.0).

Comment: I'll take a look tomorrow thanks...